# Variable reference before assignment Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, python-imaging-library

Im writing code for a function in a hangman game that occurs after a TKinter button is pressed. The tempString variable apparently is referenced before assignment and I'm extremely confused as to why.

The program randomly selects a word from txt file in which it selects an element at random from one of the lines.

Furthermore, I set up a system to detect input in an entry box which checks to see if the inputed character is in the word which has been chosen, most console commands occur for testing of game.

The update photo function changes the displayed image (series of 7, 0 = no errors 6 = full body drawn.)

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
import random

root = Tk()
i=0
failCount = 0
displayString = ""

frameLeft = Frame(root)
frameRight = Frame(root)
frameRight.pack(side=RIGHT)
frameLeft.pack(side=LEFT)

#word List
lineNumbers = 0
wordList = open("wordlist.txt", "r")
lines = wordList.readlines()
print(lines)
randomWord = lines[random.randint(0,len(lines)-1)]
print(len(lines))
print(randomWord)
for a in range(len(randomWord)-1):
        print(a)
        displayString = displayString + "~"
print(displayString)
wordList.close()


#frame Right
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("S" + str(i) + ".gif"))
imgPanel = Label(frameRight, image = img)
imgPanel.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

#frame Left

#function Declaration
entry1 = Entry(frameLeft)
entry1.pack()
labelInstruction = Label(frameLeft, text="Vape nation")
labelInstruction.pack()
def doGame():
        tempString = ""
        tempString = list(displayString)
        if str.lower(entry1.get()) in randomWord:
                labelInstruction.config(text="Yes")
                charPosition = []
                for n in range(len(randomWord)-1):
                        if randomWord[n] == entry1.get():
                                charPosition.append(n)
                for a in range(len(charPosition)):
                        tempString[charPosition[a]] = entry1.get()
                displayString = "".join(tempString)
                if randomWord == displayString:
                        print("You Win")

        elif len(entry1.get()) != 1:
                labelInstruction.config(text="Entered line is unacceptable single characters only.")
        else:
                global failCount
                labelInstruction.config(text="Incorrect")
                if failCount != 6:
                        failCount +=1
                else:
                        labelInstruction.config(text="Game Over you have failed")
                updatePhoto()
def updatePhoto():
        i = failCount
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("S" + str(i) + ".gif"))
        imgPanel.configure(image=img)
        imgPanel.image = img
submitButton = Button(frameLeft, text="Submit", command=doGame)
submitButton.pack()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Remove `global tempString` from your function.

Comment: The same error occurs.

Comment: Where is ```displayString```, ```entry1``` etc. coming from? Also, paste the full traceback so we can see what is going on

Comment: I updated it with more explanation to show the full code.